# How cast char symbol "+" directly to an operation + (addition) ? C++

Tags: c++, types, casting

Here is the issue, I have a `char` symbol:

```
char a = '+'; //- * % whatever arithmetic symbol
```

I want so that I could use the value of `a` as an operation. I don't want to use a `switch` to check if `a` is `'+'`, etc, and then write a lot of similar lines for each `case`. I need just to change the operation, depending on the value of `a`:

```
int b = 2a2; //b=4 if a = "+", b = 0 if a = "-" etc
```

But I don't know how to cast the `char` to an operation quickly. C++ has `stoi()` to cast a string to an integer, but how to cast a `char` to an operation?

By the way, which type of data is `+`? In expression like `2+2`, `2` is an integer, but what is `+`? Is it a method or what?

Comment: it is a little puzzling when you ask to avoid lots of code when it isnt clear what you mean by that. You need a switch in one way or the other, but I don't see that each case must be more than a single line of code. If you have a solution that you don't like for some reason, you should show the code

Comment: `+` is an **operator**.  It isn't data at all and it doesn't have a type.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 no, it`s not huge or inconvinient. I just thought there could exist some better and elegant solution

Comment: "better" only makes sense in comparison to something. Nevermind, I think you got the answer you were looking for

Comment: The basic problem is that C++ is generally a *compiled* language - all the machine code is generated at compile time, and you can't just decide at runtime to execute something that wasn't already in the source code.  *Interpreted* languages can have features like `eval` to turn data into code at runtime (with all the accompanying problems), but C++ isn't that.

Comment: @NateEldredge the essence of what you say is right, but consider that Python can be implemented in C++, also `eval` can be implemented  in C++, it just doesn't come as easily as in interpreted languages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want so that I could use the value of `a` as an operation.

Sorry, but that is simply not possible.  Well, not the way you have written it, anyway (there probably are low-level ways to implement something like that using self-modifying code at runtime, but that is an advanced technique I won't get into).

> I don't want to use a `switch` to check if `a` is `'+'`, etc

That would be the simplest solution.  Well, I mean, it doesn't need to be a `switch` specifically, but *something* that compares `a` to the desired values and then invokes the appropriate code for the matching value.

> I need just to change the operation, depending on the value of `a`.

I would use a `std::(unordered_)map` for this, eg:

```cpp
#include <unordered_map>
#include <functional>

const std::unordered_map<char, std::function<int(int, int)>> operations = {
    {'+', [](int a, int b){ return a + b; }},
    {'-', [](int a, int b){ return a - b; }},
    {'*', [](int a, int b){ return a * b; }},
    {'/', [](int a, int b){ return a / b; }},
    {'%', [](int a, int b){ return a % b; }},
    // etc...
};

char a = '+';
auto op = operations.at(a);
int b = op(2, 2);
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/3fKgIT)

> But I don't know how to cast the `char` to an operation quickly. C++ has `stoi()` to cast a string to an integer, but how to cast a `char` to an operation?

You can't, well not the way you are thinking of.

> By the way, which type of data is `+`? In an expression like `2+2`, `2` is an integer, but what is `+`? Is it a method or what?

It is not a type at all.  It is an operator.

Comment: :-) I think, just to be very clear about this, that you should maybe say at least once explicitly that they can't.  .... Oh, wait....

Comment: Okay, I will remember this xdd
Thank you for suggestion `std::(unordered_)map`, however it`s rather complicated for my purposes

Comment: @Cognosce this is the most simple way I am aware of. Don't make the mistake of thinking it is complicated, because you don't know it yet. You only have to cross that small barrier of knowing how to use it, from then on you benefit. I mean it wasnt made to be compilcated, but to be easy to use, and it is just the right tool for the job.

Comment: a simple `switch` would do

Answer (score 4):

I completely agree with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67608413/4117728). You cannot directly cast between `'-'` and the operator `-`. You need a switch in one way or the other and as the other answer suggests, a `unordered_map` comes in very handy.

However, there is a different view on your question...

You can convert instances of custom classes to and from basically anything you like. You can for example write a `operation` class that can be constructed from a `char`:

```
#include <iostream>

struct operation {
    enum type{ plus,minus};    
    type t;
    operation(char c){
        if (c == '+') t= plus;
        else if (c == '-') t = minus;
        else throw "unknown operator";
    }
    int operator()(int a,int b){
        if (t == plus) return a+b;
        else if (t == minus) return a-b;
        else throw "unknown operator";
    }
};

int main() {
    std::cout << operation('+')(3,1);
}
```

Note that the `if-else` could be a `switch` too. A `swtich` can be more efficient than a long chain of `if-else`, though personally I prefer `if-else` for small number of options. The switch you wanted to avoid is still there.

Now when you have a function that expects an `operation`, you can pass a `'-'` and the character is implicitly converted to an `operation`:

```
void foo(operation op){ }
foo('-');
```

Take all this with a grain of salt. I only focused on the "I want to cast" aspect but nothing else. In particular, I would actually recommend no implicit casts, because they can be confusing. Sometimes they are just right, thats up to you to decide, which isn't always easy.